# which solution is best for performance on mongoDB NoSql database

Tags: angular, typescript, mongodb

I have two idea, but I don't know which are the best solution.
FIRST Scenario:

**EDIT:** the size of ingredients can be 2000/3000 items

one structure of data like this:

```
export const ingredients = [
    {
        id       : '8f011ac5-b71c-4cd7-a317-857dcd7d85e0',
        title    : 'Strawberry',
        content  : 'Strawberry',
        allergens: ['20b9-44d9-f47c92e5-917f-9ff4ad25df00'],
        image    : 'assets/images/cards/fragola.jpg',
        labels   : ['e2f749f5-41ed-49d0-a92a-1c83d879e371'],
        status   : 'public',
        owner    : 'admin',
        favorites : false,
        createdAt: moment().hour(10).minute(19).subtract(98, 'day').toISOString(),
        updatedAt: null
    },
    {
        id       : 'ced0a1ce-051d-41a3-b080-e2161e4ae621',
        title    : 'Choccolate Mix',
        content  : 'Choccolate Mix',
        allergens: ['20b9-44d9-f47c92e5-917f-9ff4ad25df00'],
        image    : '',
        labels   : [
            'bbc73458-940b-421c-8d5f-8dcd23a9b0d6',
            'b1cde9ee-e54d-4142-ad8b-cf55dafc9528'
        ],
        status   : 'public',
        owner    : 'admin',
        favorites : false,
        createdAt: moment().hour(15).minute(37).subtract(80, 'day').toISOString(),
        updatedAt: null
    },
```

...
...

```
export const allergens = [
    {
        id   : '20b9-44d9-f47c92e5-917f-9ff4ad25df00',
        name: 'Dairy',
        status: true,
        image: 'assets/icons/allergens/00_ic_allergen_DairyProducts.svg'
    },
    {
        id   : '20b9-44d9-f47c92e5-917f-9ff4ad25df01',
        name: 'Egg',
        status: true,
        image: 'assets/icons/allergens/01_ic_allergen_Egg.svg'
    },
```

...
where in the ingredient array there are only the ID of the allergen of ingredient

SECOND Scenario:

```
export const ingredients = [
    {
        id       : '8f011ac5-b71c-4cd7-a317-857dcd7d85e0',
        title    : 'Strawberry',
        content  : 'Strawberry',
        allergens: allergens: [
        {gluten:                {checked: false,
            image: 'assets/icons/allergens/02_ic_allergen_Gluten.svg'
            types: [
                {wheat:         {checked: false}},
                {spelt:         {checked: false}},
                {khorasan:      {checked: false}},
                {rye:           {checked: false}},
                {barley:        {checked: false}},
                {oats:          {checked: false}},
        ]}},
        {shellfish:             {checked: false, image: 'assets/icons/allergens/11_ic_allergen_Crustaceans.svg'}},
        {eggs:                  {checked: false, image: 'assets/icons/allergens/01_ic_allergen_Egg.svg'}},
        {fish:                  {checked: false, image: 'assets/icons/allergens/13_ic_allergen_Fish.svg'}},
        {peanut:                {checked: false, image: 'assets/icons/allergens/05_ic_allergen_Peanuts.svg'}},
        {soyabeans:             {checked: false, image: 'assets/icons/allergens/04_ic_allergen_Soy.svg'}},
        {milk:                  {checked: false, image: 'assets/icons/allergens/00_ic_allergen_DairyProducts.svg'}},
        {nuts:                  {checked: false,
            image: 'assets/icons/allergens/03_ic_allergen_PeelFruits.svg'
            types: [
                {almond:        {checked: false}},
                {hazelnuts:     {checked: false}},
                {walnuts:       {checked: false}},
                {cashewnuts:    {checked: false}},
                {pecans:        {checked: false}},
                {brazilnuts:    {checked: false}},
                {macadamianuts: {checked: false}},
                {pistachios:    {checked: false}}
        ]}},
        {celery:                {checked: false, image: 'assets/icons/allergens/10_ic_allergen_Celery.svg'}},
        {mustard:               {checked: false, image: 'assets/icons/allergens/09_ic_allergen_Mustard.svg'}},
        {sesame:                {checked: false, image: 'assets/icons/allergens/08_ic_allergen_SesameGrains.svg'}},
        {sulfites:              {checked: false, image: 'assets/icons/allergens/06_ic_allergen_Sulphites.svg'}},
        {lupini:                {checked: false, image: 'assets/icons/allergens/07_ic_allergen_Lupins.svg'}},
        {clams:                 {checked: false, image: 'assets/icons/allergens/12_ic_allergen_Mollusks.svg'}}
    ],
        image    : 'assets/images/cards/fragola.jpg',
        labels   : ['e2f749f5-41ed-49d0-a92a-1c83d879e371'],
        status   : 'public',
        owner    : 'admin',
        favorites : false,
        createdAt: moment().hour(10).minute(19).subtract(98, 'day').toISOString(),
        updatedAt: null
    },
```

for every ingredient I have the structure complete of the allergen of ingredient.
I'm build one APP in Angular with backend in Node with a REST API connection, but in the future I would like to rewrite the backend with GraphQL API.
Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: whats the size of `allergens` fields ?

Comment: I edit my question, the size of ingredients can be 2000/3000 items, so for every ingredient can be 2/3/4 allergen max usually

Comment: getting  ingredient full object with allergen in object ,
if all allergen be in ingredient for collecting data I think the performance is better than relation object
but if you want to switch to graphQL for designing schema I think relational is easier

Comment: my intuition I would opt for the first solution